# Swapping rows and labels in contingency table output

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there anyway to swap the rows in the contingency table like SURV => 0 at bottom, SURV => 1 at top of it. Also `LIT` label shold be bottom as shown below

[image]

```r
library(QCA)
#> Warning: package 'QCA' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> Loading required package: admisc
#> Warning: package 'admisc' was built under R version 3.6.3
#> 
#> To cite package QCA in publications, please use:
#>   Dusa, Adrian (2019) QCA with R. A Comprehensive Resource.
#>   Springer International Publishing.
#> 
#> To run the graphical user interface, use: runGUI()
with(LC, table(SURV, LIT))
#>     LIT
#> SURV 0 1
#>    0 5 5
#>    1 0 8
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change them to factors and specify the order of `levels`.

```
LC <- data.frame(SURV = sample(0:1, 10, TRUE),
                  LIT = sample(0:1, 10, TRUE))
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
LC %>% 
  mutate(across(c(SURV, LIT), ~ factor(., levels = c(1, 0)))) %>% 
           with(table(SURV, LIT))
# output
    LIT
SURV 1 0
   1 4 3
   0 2 1
```

Making the label print at the bottom you'd have to use some package or change the "print" method for `table` class objects.

Comment: can't we simply swap the rows after we got the contingency table with like ```%>% something()```

Comment: You'd have to switch both the rows and columns to change the order of "0" and "1". As for the dimension names, this is more difficult. `print.table` calls `print.matrix`. The dimension and their names are not rows/columns themselves, but rather attributes. I would say the above is the "simplest" solution. But there are myriad table packages out there, maybe one has even options to change printing behaviour of those 2. But they would've had to implement this as well. :-)